# Converting BitmapDrawable into an imageView

Tags: java, android

I have a particular scenario, I'm very close to finishing! Basically, I've got some decodeBase64 strings in a database that need to be used in a BitmapFactory and then drawn.

```
public static Bitmap decodeBase64(String input)
  {
    byte[] decodedByte = Base64.decode(input, 0);
    return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedByte, 0, decodedByte.length);
  }
```

Here is my MainActivity.java:

```
    // Initiate Database
        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this); // "this" refer to the context
    // Grab current Car for use.
        Car cars = db.getCurrentCar();
    // Grab String from database and decode to Base64
        //ByteConvert.decodeBase64(cars.get_image());
    // Create Bitmap object from database source
        BitmapFactory(ByteConvert.decodeBase64(cars.get_image());
    // Draw image from string
    Drawable draw = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), BITMAPFACTORY GOES HERE);
    // Set R.id.DRAWABLE to imageView
```

My question, is how do I turn this string I'm returning from decodeBase64 into a BitmapFactory and then Draw it?

I have done my best to try and fill out how I think it works.

Thanks

Comment: I dont understand, you just want to show the bitmap you decoded in an imageview?

Comment: Yeah why do you need a second BitmapFactory and the drawable object? Why not the following works for you? imageView.setImageBitmap(ByteConvert.decodeBase64(cars.get_image());

Comment: Basically, the image is a string in the database which was encodedTobase64(); I need to take it out of the database and reconstruct it.

@yygyt I'm not sure what you mean? That imageView snipped won't convert the decoded string into an image? I thought I had to use BitmapFactory to reconstruct it and then put it inside an imageView?

Comment: "You have an image view called `imageView` and you want it to show the bitmap that is kept as a string in the db" am I correct?

Comment: I suggest you consider storing the bitmaps themselves, in the file system.  Store the names of the file in the DB.  Storing large objects in your database is going to lead to very poor performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Base64.decode method is returning a byte array, so you can use BitmapFactory's decodeByteArray method to build your bitmap, and set it on your ImageView.

Ex:

```
DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
Car cars = db.getCurrentCar();
byte[] imageData = Base64.decode(cars.get_image(), 0);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0, imageData.length, new BitmapFactory.Options());
ImageView imageView = //find your image view;
imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Comment: Am I right in thinking to do an ImageView it should be ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.IMAGEID);

Comment: Yes, well, ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IMAGEID);